# RSS and atom feed notifier for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, rss, feed, atom-feed

I am looking for a convenience feed-notifier for Mac OS X similar to e.g. [Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/), which pops up notifications for new items in the feeds.

*Edit:* Growl looks like the right direction, but I am missing something optimized on regular updates suitable for e.g. Stackoverflow - update times of e.g. 30 minutes are way too long.

Popup example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://growl.info/applications.php?cat=Feed+Readers

Growl is a framework for pop-up notifications and there are many feed readers that support it.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

http://www.rssowl.org/download

Cross platform, open source.  You can configure the notifications.

Comment: Last activity 2015. No longer supported and does not work on Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I'm the developer of Feed Notifier and I just released a port of it for Mac OS X. Hope this helps someone!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feed-notifier/id571150542?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: does not support authenticated feeds though